# Xorg on skylake graphics hangs

Tags: kernel, xorg, intel

I've bought msi gs40 that has intel i7 6700HQ which means integrated graphics hd 530. After a day of struggling I was able to start xorg with HD530. For this I addes [i915](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#Enable_early_KMS) to initramfs and [i915.preliminary_hw_support=1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#Configuration) to kernel params. But xorg hangs in the end of the day, sometime right after start, sometimes after a few hours of using. I tried archlinux with:

- xorg 1.6, 1.7, 1.8
- kernels 4.2.5-1, 4.3, 4.4-rc4, 4.4-rc5
- cinnamon, plasma5
- latest intel driver in archlinux repository and compiled intel driver from git.
- [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#X_freeze.2Fcrash_with_intel_driver) suggestion: `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` and Xorg `Option "DRI" "False"`
- ubuntu and Linux Mint (both freeze right after start). OS Windows runs fine.

Everything just freezes after some time of using and I got glib stacktrace in journalctl(meanwhile xorg.log and dmesg are fine) Sometimes I get `couldn't open dis display :0` in dmesg and applications refuse to start. journalctl kde's shows `Bad windows`, cinnamon's other errors. [Here](https://gist.github.com/Deathangel908/8d654e7575314b3aabc3)'s the dmesg of system startup with 4.4-rc5 kernel without external displays.

- There are no errors in dmesg and xorg when xorg hangs if I work only with laptop's display (just DE errors described above).
- If I run HDMI/DP external display I would also get dmesg [stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/Deathangel908/8d654e7575314b3aabc3#L1135) like a bonus when Xorg hangs, looks like [this](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=89055) bug issue.

Related topics:

- Mine question on [Archlinux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1586560#p1586560)
- The guy from [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/698168/cant-get-intel-hd-graphics-530-skylake-i7-6700-to-work) was able run HD530 from the same cpu (6700hq) with LinuxMint. I tried the same, didn't work.

If you require additional information please tell me. Any kind of help is greatly appreciated!